In my polytheistic world, how should I prevent people fighting over which god to worship?
Remember when I set the protagonist, Berta Newton (Issac Newton's incarnation into isekai), as an angel? As the accepted answerer aptly said, people will be interested in her magics themselves, rather than the science she's going to teach.
After some time, I found a solution. Namely, instead of an angel, let Berta be a god. A god is whom to be worshipped. People will consider Berta's magics to be divine actions, and not to be a subject of scientific investigation. Though even Berta herself won't understand how her magics work, in this way, her mission to teach people science can go well.
But there is one problem. What if another god joins the isekai? The next gods in queue are Paula Dalton (incarnation of John Dalton), Ludwig Mendel (incarnation of Gregor Mendel), Theodor Mohs (incarnation of Friedrich Mohs), and so on. Sure, their represented branches of sciences aren't contradictory, and people can worship them together. But still, some people might argue over silly things like 'which god is the mightiest' or 'which god is the most beneficial to worship'.
There are some gods that are especially perilous for Berta, namely Dora Einstein (incarnation of Albert Einstein) and Otto Heisenberg (incarnation of Werner Heisenberg). Their physics, namely relativity theory and quantum mechanics, "contradict"
classical mechanics. Sure, the philosophy of science states that this is more like a correction than a rebuttal, but I can easily imagine people getting confused. After all, it would look like gods are fighting, even when Berta would be convinced with the new theories. At worst, some people might be thoroughly disappointed and become anti-theists who are easily deceived by pseudo-sciences.
Indeed, there are such people in our reality as well. Those people think Einstein had "defeated" Newton and thus science is inconsistent.
Should I just accept such people would emerge in my world just like in our reality, or do I have a strategy to prevent that?

Interesting that the other quesiton wasn't closed as asking what to write...

Maybe you should ask this in worldbuilding.stackexchange.com, since you are asking how to build a pantheon without disputes among worshippers.

Historically, polytheistic cultures didn’t fight over which gods to worship.   The Romans and Greeks didn’t war over choices of household gods. A common element of polytheistic beliefs was the separation between whom made the world and the gods, and the gods themselves. The gods get the worship because that is what they desire. The creators of the gods were indifferent to humanity's devotion and prayers. For instance, no one worshiped the Titans.
The dualistic and monotheistic religions were the ones that got in a snit about their neighbors’ choice of god.  Especially the dualistic beliefs like Manicheanism.  When one god is good and the other is evil, then respetive followers are intrinsically at odds with each other.
Dr. Harari’s lectures from the book are available on Youtube

The assessment that only monotheistic religions are in competition with each other is based on a widespread absence of historical sources from many places and periods. The wars between the Dalai Lamas in Tibet, the Chinese wars between different Taoist sects, the Mesopotamian practice of subjugating the god of a conquered people, the systematic killing of adherents of competing religions in ancient India and so on, indicate that religion has probably always played a central part in political power struggles. And monotheistic violence has often been politically motivated – or fuelled – as well.

@Ben, the observation  only applies to believers within the same tradition. Worshipers of Odin generally didn’t slaughter worshipers of Thor because they worshiped Thor. Same applies to Horus and Isis.

That's not what your answer implies. Your answer implies that wars between polytheistic religions are nonexistent. You answer, if I go by your comment, compares apples to oranges. Monotheistic religions are mostly free of that kind of internal conflicts as well. The catholics that pray to Mother Mary also don't go to war with those who pray to Jesus.

@Ben,  that’s your interpretation of my answer. The real question is why do you care? This is another example of your dysfunctional aggression. It is really weird that you troll other peoples answers.

In a polytheistic society, people worship all the relevant gods.  And they have no objections to their neighbors worshipping the gods relevant to them.
The biggest conflict is when societies regard a god as foreign and therefore suitable to be worshipped by the foreigners living among you (and in their own country) but not by your people, because it is not the practice of your forefathers.

You're asking how to avoid conflict in your story.
This, to me, is the wrong question to ask about narrative fiction (I assume this is that).
Conflict is the lifeblood of good stories... your question should rather be, how can I have more conflict?
All the potential problems you list sound like terrific fuel for larger or smaller conflicts that you should definitely explore. You might find some really profound things you can hint at about the human condition in these conflicts.
Of course, if your story isn't about religious conflict or similar subjects, my suggestion is, write the first draft without religious conflicts, and fix all the problems it will have. Maybe the lack of religious conflict is one of them, maybe it's not. You'll likely get a pretty good feel for the answer once you have the finished draft.

Random conflict is merely confusion, not a story.  If this conflict would distract from the story proper, it is bad.

What? Who said anything about random conflict? A writer that cannot add conflict to their work without it becoming random probably shouldn't quit their day job. I guess I must add that you should produce a working story as well.
